# What will be the time complexity of this code fragment?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

Given this question where increment over the iterator i happens by incrementing its value by its own log value. What will be the big O time complexity for this fragment?

```
i = 10
while(i<n) {
    i=i+log(i);
}
```

Comment: Hi Aditya, you missed defining n.

Comment: There is no defined value of n. We have to find big O complexity in terms of n.

Comment: Interesting question. Where did you find this piece of code?

Comment: @templatetypedef this was given in one of my class assignments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question! Here's an initial step toward working out the runtime.

Let's imagine that we have reached a point in the loop where the value of i has reached 2<sup>k</sup> for some natural number k. Then for i to increase to 2<sup>k+1</sup>, we'll need approximately 2<sup>k</sup> / k iterations to elapse. Why? That's because

- The amount i needs to increase is 2<sup>k+1</sup> - 2<sup>k</sup> = 2<sup>k</sup>(2 - 1) = 2<sup>k</sup>, and
- At each step, increasing i by log i will increase i by roughly log 2<sup>k</sup> = k.

We can therefore break the algorithm apart into "stages." In the first stage, we grow from size 2<sup>3</sup> to size 2<sup>4</sup>, requiring (roughly) 2<sup>3</sup>/3 steps. In the second stage, we grow from size 2<sup>4</sup> to size 2<sup>5</sup>, requiring (roughly) 2<sup>4</sup> / 4 steps. After repeating this process many times, we eventually grow from size n/2 = 2<sup>log n - 1</sup> to size n = 2<sup>log n</sup>, requiring (roughly) 2<sup>log n</sup> / log n steps. The total amount of work done is therefore given by

> 2<sup>3</sup> / 3 + 2<sup>4</sup>/4 + 2<sup>5</sup> / 5 + ... + 2<sup>log n</sup> / log n.

The goal now is to find some bounds on this expression. We can see that the sum is at least equal to its last term, which is 2<sup>log n</sup> / log n = n / log n, so the work done is Ω(n / log n). We can also see that the work done is less than

> 2<sup>3</sup> + 2<sup>4</sup> + 2<sup>5</sup> + ... + 2<sup>log n</sup>
>
> ≤ 2<sup>log n + 1</sup> *(sum of a geometric series)*
>
> = 2n,

so the work done is O(n). That sandwiches the runtime between Ω(n / log n) and O(n).

It turns out that **Θ(n / log n)** is indeed a tight bound here, which can be proved by doing a [more nuanced analysis of the summation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/888354/asymptotic-behavior-of-sum-limits-k-1n-frac2kk).

Comment: Great explanation! 

While calculating the steps required to go from 2^k to 2^(k+1), after a certain point log(k) will start contributing more than k. This will be very significant as we approach larger powers of 2. Can we still assume that the lower bound will be n/log(n)?

Comment: If i is between 2^k and 2^{k+1}, then log i will be between k and k+1. So perhaps it would be better to reframe the fractions as having the form 2^k / (k+1). But this won't make much of a difference, as it adds only +/- 1 to each of only O(log n) total terms.

Comment: simpler, but not rigorous by any means, it's just the number of primes below `n`, asymptotically, since `log i` is precisely an "average" gap between primes around `i`. so indeed it is ~ n/log n.

Answer (score 0):

Let us look a bit about the definition of *g(n)=O(f(n))*: saying the function g is of order O(f(n)) means there exists a number n0 and a constant c such that for all *n>n0* it is *g(n)<=cf(n)*.

Looking at the worst case scenario, the while will run for maximum *n* times which means we can say your code is of order *O(n)*.

Now let's assume that the code inside the while loop is

```
(*) while(i<n) {
       i = i + i ;
   }
```

which obviously should skip more iteration that the original one. So we can use this code to estimate a lower bound. Examining *(*)* we see that in each iteration the counter will be double, if we think a little bit about it we see that for n iteration each time half of the input will be thrown out. so the code in (*) will have worst case asymptotic runtime *O(log n)*.

Now we estimate that the original code should be between both so we can say its asymptotic lower bound is *Ω(log n)* and its asymptotic upper bound is *O(n)*.